# presonus pulseaudio mic level low

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, skype, microphone

I have 5.15.0-43-generic, 20.04.1-Ubuntu.
I have a Presonus studio 68C audio interface and I would like to use my condenser mic with e.g skype, google meet or teams softwares. I noticed that the mic level is very low. I went to alsamixer, but there is no volume control. I tried with pavucontrol to increase input the gain to 153%. It is better but still low. I tried to increase to 300% using command line, but I start to get a very bad quality audio.
I noticed that users of Focusrite scarlett cards had similar problem but I can't find a clear solution.
There is no problem to record with audacity or Ardour, with ASLA or with JACK inputs. The levels are perfect. It seems to be specific to pulseaudio but I could not find a solution after many hours of search.

If anyone can help me with this I would be very appreciative.

Comment: If your system is reporting 20.04.1 then it is severely out of date.  Please bring your system up-to-date and see if this resolves your issue.  If you still have a problem, please share the details of what you've done so far. If you've made changes to configurations, please share those changes with us. Edit your question with these details and use the formatting tools provided to use monospace formatting where appropriate so that we can distinguish your details from surrounding text.

Comment: Are you using a supported kernel? If you are using an unsupported kernel, then you may be subject to bugs and other problems with hardware. It's recommended that you use a supported kernel when diagnosing potential hardware issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your comments.
I updated Ubuntu to 22.04 but I the problem remained.
I have search a lot through internet and I found a solution.

The problem comes that the audio interface creates a multi-inputs sink (5 channels), however using one microphone, only one channel is used and so only 1/5th of the mic level can be reached. So a solution was to map the channel (front-left) to a mono sink using the command:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-source source_name=Presonus_Left_Mic source_properties="device.description=Presonus_Left_In" master=alsa_input.usb-PreSonus_Studio_68c_01329742-00.multichannel-input master_channel_map=front-left channel_map=mono
```

the master name is found using:

```
pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

For permanent solution, append the command (without pacmd) in /etc/pulse/default.pa.

Thank you again.